# PHP MYSQL INSERT in row if NOT exist or Show content from DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a script, which gets titles and ids from youtube using Curl and saves them to a database with the following structure: id | title | id_youtube | date.

The problem is I need a code so that if the title already exists in db that shows the contents from db, otherwise curl to process and store it in the DB.

```
id_youtube($q); // this function get the id_youtube
title_youtube($q); // this function get the youtube title

$id = id_youtube($q);
$q = title_youtube($q);

This is my code to insert values to DB

mysql_connect('localhost', 'db_user', 'pw_name') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('db_name') or die($connect_error);

mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO posts (id, title, id_youtube,date) VALUES (null,'$q', '$id',now())");
```

right now, just saves to DB, and if exist, again insert in new row (dupicate row), I need ssomething like:

```
if $q already exist {

//query to show content from DB


}else{
// Code tu get titles and ids WHIT Curl
//mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO posts (id, title, id_youtube,date) VALUES (null,'$q', '$id',now())");

}
```

any help ?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: I take this into consideration, but right now I use another php Version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do a query that try to find a row with the id_youtube you are analyzing. If the query return at least one row (actually only one row), you will get the info using a second query, else you will do the insert query.

Something like this pseudo code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id_youtube = '$id' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)  == 1)
    $query = "SELECT yourColumns FROM posts WHERE id_youtube = '$id'";
    display_the_info();
else
    mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO posts (id, title, id_youtube,date) VALUES (null,'$q', '$id',now())");
```

You should also use **myslqi** functions, not mysql one.